# Iterables.transform is not iterating through my List

Tags: java, collections, guava

analyticsDatabases is of type -

```
private final Iterable<Database> analyticsDatabases;
```

And I use below code snippet inside a method, and I have one element in analyticsDatabases List. When I do a for loop all works fine, but I am curious why my Iterables.transform doesn't work.

```
Iterable<Iterable<ObjectId>> finalR = Iterables.transform(analyticsDatabases, new Function<Database, Iterable<ObjectId>>() { 
    @Nullable 
    @Override 
    public Iterable<ObjectId> apply(@Nullable Database database) { 
        if (database != null) { 
            return database.deleteItemsById(filterIds, storableType, writeAckStrategy); 
        } 

        `enter code here`

        return null; 
    } 
});
```

Comment: _How_ it "doesn't work"? As Sotirios points out, `apply` is lazily evaluated, which means that the method is only called when iterating through `finalR`.

Comment: Consider using `FluentIterables.from(...).transform(...).toList()` if you want the results eagerly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javadoc of [`Iterables`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) states

> Performance notes: Unless otherwise noted, **all of the iterables
>   produced in this class are lazy**, which means that their iterators only
>   advance the backing iteration when absolutely necessary.

In other words, `transform` doesn't apply the given `Function`. It returns an `Iterable` that will apply the `Function` as elements are requested.

Comment: So does this get called if someone check hasNext or next ?

Comment: @Lahiru For `transform`, it's probably on `next()`. For `filter`, it's probably on `hasNext()`.